# Nesting HTML <span> inside rails form_for label tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, forms, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to nest a  element inside a form_for label tag.  I want to do this so I can target a specific portion of the label with CSS rules, in this case to make the text red.  From some quick reading, this does appear to be valid HTML, and it fits with my design even though the idea is not playing happily with Rails.

The desired html output is like this:
    `<label for="zip">ZIP Code -<span class="required">Required</span></label>`

My current code looks like this:
    `<%= form.label :zip, 'ZIP Code -<span class="required">Required</span>' %>`

The problem is that Rails is somehow escaping the inner span tag so that it appears as text on the page instead of HTML.  I see this on the page:
`ZIP Code -<span class="required">Required</span>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails3 automatically escapes strings.  You need to call #html_safe on the string you're putting in the label.  See http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/ for details.

Comment: Hahaha small world.. Nice to meet you, I work with your coworkers up here in Michigan BTW, though you have probably not heard of me.

Comment: Oh and thanks for the pointer to #html_safe - i knew about Rails3 auto escaping, but not that it applied to lables, or about html_safe.